# Neuroimage MRI scan CNN model preparation

Tags: conv-neural-network, medical-imaging

I would like to know a couple of things to clear my confusion. I want to work on a medical neuroimage MRI image scans dataset from the ADNI database.

Each Alzheimer's Disease (AD) MRI image scan has multiple slices.
Do I have to separate each image scan slice and label each of them as AD or combine all image scan slices as a one-image scan and label it for classification?

Most of the medical neuroimage DICOM, NfINT, NII, etc., format. Is it mandatory to convert them to png or jpg for the CNN network model or keep it in NfNIT or nii format?

I have read several existing papers on neuroimaging regarding Alzheimer's disease but did not find the above question answer. Even I have sent an email to the research paper writer in reply; I got they can not help on this as they are very busy and mention their sincere apology for that.

It will be very helpful if anyone has the answer to clear my confusion and thought.
Thank you.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, you may choose to work on 2d or 3d model. So... what do you want to do?

Comment: @DimaTisnek, well, I want to work on the ADNI dataset for AD, MCI, FTD, and NC detection and classification.

Comment: What kind of algorithm do you intend to apply? Or what kind RNN do you plan to train?

Answer (score 2):

You can train with NIfTI, using, for example, TorchIO. There's no need to separate each slice, you can use the 3D image as is.

You can find some examples in the [documentation](https://torchio.readthedocs.io/quickstart.html#tutorials).

Disclaimer: I'm the main developer of TorchIO.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Can I train with the 2D image as well instead of 3D?

Comment: Yes. Its specialty is 3D, but 2D is fine too.